# Load file in rspec before block VS load them once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails, savon

Today I'm tryng to speed up my tests suite. My application is basically a big integrator between systems so most of my tests are using Savon mocks like this

```rb
RSpec.describe MyClass do

  describe 'a function which sends a SOAP request'do
    before do
      savon.mock!
      savon.expects(action).returns(File.read("spec/fixtures/somefile.xml"))
    end

    after { savon.unmock! }

    it 'checks something'
    it 'checks something else'
    it 'checks something more'
    it 'checks something different'
  end
end
```

Obviously most of those tests are quite slow as they are loading a file. Moreover sometimes these mocks are inside nested contexts in order to combine multiple shared examples which increases the amount of loads. 
Thinking to speed up some of these tests I tried to reduce the number of file loads moving them outside the `before` block. like this

```rb
RSpec.describe MyClass do

  describe 'a function which sends a SOAP request'do
    the_file = File.read("spec/fixtures/somefile.xml")

    before do
      savon.mock!
      savon.expects(action).returns(the_file)
    end

    after { savon.unmock! }

    it 'checks something'
    it 'checks something else'
    it 'checks something more'
    it 'checks something different'
  end
end
```

Indeed, the speed does not change; I have blocks of 96 tests with multiples, nested contexts and checks and I haven't gained not even 0.01 seconds. So my questions are:

- I supposed the `before` block loads the file *for each it*, am I
  right?
- Does Rspec or Savon have some kind of cache?
- How can I track the number of times I'm *really* loading my example file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should look into the hooks order and specify something that suits you better like `before (:suite)` or `before (:context)`. Depending the one you use it will be executed

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks

Comment: That's a good idea. It works in some cases. Indeed not in all of them, as I need to change some global configuration using [ClimateControl gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/climate_control). These changes, as they are applied _per test_, force me to run the `before` block for each test as the code inside depends on the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Using let `let(:the_file) { File.read("spec/fixtures/somefile.xml") }` will solve your problem as let is lazy evaluated